# Can anyone help me find this Japanese font?

Tags: fonts, japanese

I can't seem to identify what this font is. I found it on a youtube video. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the youtube video owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [ハルクラフト](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/1277) from a major vendor モリサワ (Morisawa). It seems that you can obtain it through an English interface on [this site](https://typesquare.com/en/fontlist/fontlist) by the name "Harucraft" (disclaimer: I didn't try).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!